# Slimphp - Twig dynamic include

Tags: php, twig, slim

I need to include template dynamically in twig template. So the template will included the page that defined in routes.php

I try to concatenate string and variable like this code bellow, but still not working.

**routes.php**:

```
$app->get('/home', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $data['page'] = "home";
  return $this->view->render($response, 'Home/layout.html', $data);
});
```

**Home/layout.html:**

```
{% include 'Home/_header.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_topbar.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_sidebar.html' %}
{% include 'Home/' ~ data.page ~ '.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_footer.html' %}
```

**Error message:**

```
Unable to find template "Home/.html" (looked into: ../App/Templates) in "Home/layout.html" at line 4.
```

I found my own solution, but it's not the one i want. So I edited routes.php and layout.html like this:

**routes.php:**

```
$app->get('/home', function ($request, $response, $args) {
  $data['page'] = "{% include 'Home/home.html' %}";
  return $this->view->render($response, 'Home/layout.html', $data);
});
```

**Home/layout.html:**

```
{% include 'Home/_header.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_topbar.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_sidebar.html' %}
{% include template_from_string(page) %}
{% include 'Home/_footer.html' %}
```

What I want is to send variable that contain name of the template file from routes.php, not the template syntax instead.

Comment: Which error do you give?

Comment: @Matteo it gave me error message "Unable to find template "Home/.html" (looked into: ../App/Templates) in "Home/layout.html" at line 4."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are accessing the wrong variable. You are passing the following to `twig`,

```
$data['page'] = "home";
return $this->view->render($response, 'Home/layout.html', $data);
```

Which means to access the variable `page` inside `twig` you would just need to call `page` and not `data.page` as the array `data` is not even passed towards to your template

Which means your template should look like the following

```
{% include 'Home/_header.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_topbar.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_sidebar.html' %}
{% include 'Home/' ~ page ~ '.html' %}
{% include 'Home/_footer.html' %}
```

---

You could actually tell this by yourself when looking at the error message

> Unable to find template "Home/.html"

As there is nothing in between `Home/` and `.html`, this mean the variable `data.page` doesn't exist. I recommend to enable debug mode when developing then u would get an error you are trying to access an undefined variable

Comment: Oops, my bad. i didn't realize that. Thanks for saving my day.